# Zoom an image every one second jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I try to animate an image with zooming every one second, it work when I load my page but I want it every one second. I think when I use the same id of my image it's a problem.

This is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/UxTdU/1/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `setTimeout` which will execute some code after a certain time, what you want is `setInterval`, which will execute some code every so often. http://jsfiddle.net/UxTdU/3/

Answer (score 2):

You could just increment the `zoom` property from within an interval.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#myImg").animate({"zoom":"+=.025"}, 500);
}, 1000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UxTdU/6/

You could even zoom it up to a particular size, then stop:

```
// Cache reference to image
var $image  = jQuery("#myImg");

// Cache reference to zooming interval
var zooming = setInterval(function(){

    // If current zoom is under 1.5
    $image.css("zoom") < 1.5 

        // Increment zoom by .025
        ? $image.animate({"zoom":"+=.025"}, 500) 

        // Otherwise, stop zooming
        : clearInterval(zooming);

// Run every 1 second
}, 1000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UxTdU/8/

Comment: And you fixed his logic... ah, initiative! (:

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/UxTdU/5/ - use setInterval, not setTimeout. setTimeout happens only once.